# Show data depending on the time of the day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that shows the amount of units produced by an employee. It also has the transaction time.

Is it possible to display data in such a way that when the current time is between 7 am to 3 pm it should only display the transaction that took place during that period of time and then when the current time is 3pm then it should only display the transactions between 3-11 pm.

sample data

```
units | name | TIME
-------------------------
 10 | aa       | 08:33:22
 26 | bb       | 10:33:22
 36 | cc       | 16:33:22
 11 | dd       | 18:33:22
```

Now if the current time is 13:00:00 i want all the transcations between 7am to 3pm which will be just the first 2. But when the time is 15:00:00 then it should automatically show all the transactions between 3pm - 11pm

Comment: You should edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where`:

```
where (datepart(hour, getdate()) between 7 and 14 and
       datepart(hour, transactiondatetime) between 7 and 14
      ) or
      (datepart(hour, getdate()) not between 7 and 14 and
       datepart(hour, transactiondatetime) between 11 and 22
      )
```

Comment: Looks like OP want the second condition only show the range `between 14 and 23`